# Python: Why does %r not accurately represent the raw data on \" versus \'

Tags: python

I've been going through Zed's LPTHW and I have been messing around with escape characters after doing lesson 10.  While fooling around with %r I came across this, and I have no idea why it's happening (I'm so new to any form of programming/coding it hurts):

```
test = "10'5\""
test_2 = '10\'5"'

print "%r" % test
print "%r" % test_2
```

When I run this, I get:

```
'10\'5"'
'10\'5"'
```

I'm confused.  I had assumed that I would get output in the following:

```
"10'5\"'
'10\'5"'
```

It was my understanding that %r would return the string identical to how it is written, yet it seems to convert it to test_2 by moving the \ to the left.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It was my understanding that %r would return the string identical to how it is written

Your understanding is incorrect. Python does not "remember" how a string was written in the source code; all that matters to the interpreter is that it contains the characters:

```
10'5"
```

Printing a `repr` of that string will use whichever type of quotation marks Python feels is most appropriate for its contents. Since both strings contain the same characters, they are printed identically by `repr` (and, hence, by the `%r` format string).

Answer (score 0):

Python string literals or constants can start either with a single-quote(') or a double-quote("). When it begins with a single-quote('), then it must end with a with a single-quote(').

And the similar logic goes for a string literal or constant beginning with with a double-quote("). If it begins with a double-quote ("), then it must end with the same double-quote(").

Now the interesting thing to notice here is: if a string literal or constant begins with a double-quote("), then the single-quote(') inside that string literal is just another character. You don't need to put the escape character (\) to tell Python interpreter to retain that single-quote(') intact.

And the similar logic goes for a string literal or constant that begins with a single-quote('), then the double-quote(") inside that string literal is just another character. You don't need to put the escape character (\) to tell Python interpreter to retain that double-quote(") intact.

So in your following code fragment, you initialized your variable `test` with a string literal or constant. You defined your string constant by the double- quotes("..."). Inside your string constant, you put two digits (10), a single- quote('), digit(5), and a double-quote (which needed escaping by the escape character).

You did the same thing for your variable `test_2` in your following code fragment. But here you defined your string literal or constant using the single-quotes('...'), so you needed to escape the single-quote(') after the first two digits(10).

```
test = "10'5\""   
test_2 = '10\'5"'

print "%r" % test
print "%r" % test_2
```

If you print your variables using the print format `%s` instead of the raw format `%r` as following, you will get the same string literal or constant value for both the variables, which is: `10'5"`

```
print "%s" % test
print "%s" % test_2
```

But for the raw format `%r` value of your two Python string variables `test` and `test_2`, the Python interpreter internally chose to represent your raw string value beginning and ending with a single-quote, and printing both as : `'10\'5"'`. This has no bearing on how you defined your string literals, using either the double-quotes("...") or the single-quotes('...').